# Extract non-negative number from the ending of a string in js

Tags: javascript

Just like the title says
Description of the example:
x) example string -> what I need as the output

examples:

```
1) "asdf"      ->    null or -1 or undefined (because nothing was found)
2) "asdf1"     ->    1
3) "asdf0"     ->    0
4) "asdf-1"    ->    1
5) "asdf001"   ->    1
6) "asdf1234"  ->    1234
7) "asdf12.34" ->    34 (ending value, so number after .)
8) "123asdf78" ->    78 (integer from ending)
```

I hope these examples will be enough. I tried doing this with for loop, but it didn't work out. Does anyone know if there are functions which enable to do something like this or similar?

More info about my approach:
In the for loop I checked for every character if is  >= '0' && <= '9' then added to previous tmp variable which responsible for concatenate all characters, and at the end I parsed this to int. But I think this solution is bad...

Comment: Yes, i wrote it in the ending of the post...

Comment: Just perform the loop from reverse and once you find a character break it and then output the extracted number.

Comment: Okay then, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple regular expression for this purpose:

```js
function numericSuffix(string) {
    const match = string.match(/\d+$/);
    return match !== null ? Number(match[0]) : null;
}

numericSuffix('abc-123') // 123
numericSuffix('abc-123x') // null
```